# Correct type annotation for a view function which takes no argument

Tags: html, elm

I'm currently learning Elm and I know this a noob question but I can't seem to properly type annotate this function which return just a pure div.

```
header =
    div [] [ text "Hello" ]
```

What would be accurate way to type annotate this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct annotation is this:

```
header : Html msg
header =
    div [] [ text "Hello" ]
```

In the future, you can use the Elm REPL to find the type of something:

```plain
> import Html exposing (..)
> div [] [ text "Hello" ]
{ type = "node", tag = "div", facts = {}, children = {}, namespace = <internal structure>, descendantsCount = 0 }
: Html.Html msg
```

The part after the colon specifies the signature, which is `Html.Html msg`